# Execute the CutyCapt commands using c# code

Tags: c#

I am new to C# code, I need to run the below commands by using C# code, Could any one give me the full code for this one?

### Command :

```
C:\\Srinivasa\\VisualStudioProject\\CutyCapt_Pdf_Code\\release\\CutyCapt.exe
```

### Arguments :

```
--url=file:///C:/Users/UPPALASX/Desktop/New%20folder/ResearchMap.html 
--out=Out_Embeded_RM.png 
--min-width=800 
--min-height=10000
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me to resolve my issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This:

```
Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "C:\\Srinivasa\\VisualStudioProject\\CutyCapt_Pdf_Code\\
              release\\CutyCapt.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "--url=\'C:/Users/UPPALASX/Desktop/New 
             folder/ResearchMap.html\' --out=Out_Embeded_RM.png --min-width=800
             --min-height=10000";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: You chose to answer a poorly-researched question. That's your prerogative. However, copy-pasting a block of code from an answer in the duplicate then modifying some property values to suit the questioner's specific problem does not strike me as the right thing to do. Maybe you could provide attribution to the [source answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1469790/464709).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: sorry dear, i never copy paste any answer from anywhere it was just tried in my VS and posted here.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e8zac0ca.aspx) and [Process.StartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo.aspx)